# PIC32MX795F512H UART1 interrupt problem

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I know this topic has already been brought up and I have been going through those posts but I still can't get my UART1 RX interrupt working. What I am trying to do is receive the NMEA string from my GPS module which I can see is being delivered to the UART RX pin after inspection with an oscilloscope.

These characters that I am receiving I want to then display on an LCD display which is a piece of the code that I already have running. What I don't understand is why an interrupt is not being triggered when characters are being sent to the UART1 port? I will attach my main() and ISR routine. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
main()
{
        InitApp();             //initialise ports 
        intLCD();              //initialise LCD
        clrLCD();
        putsLCD("Initialising \n \t TCAS");
        INTEnableSystemMultiVectoredInt();
        //UART
        U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1; //enable UART1
        U1MODEbits.PDSEL = 0;   //8 bits, no parity
        U1MODEbits.STSEL = 0; //1 stop bit used
        U1BRG = 1041; //set baud rate to 4800
        U1STAbits.URXISEL = 0; //interrupt flag bit is set when a character is received

        PORTSetPinsDigitalOut(IOPORT_F, BIT_5);                    //data transmitter
        PORTSetPinsDigitalIn(IOPORT_F, BIT_4);                     //data receiver

        //interrupts
        IEC0bits.U1RXIE = 1;   //enable interrupt
        U1STAbits.URXISEL = 0; //interrupt after character is received

        gpsINITIALISE();        //initialise GPS to receive data
        int check = 0;
        while(1)
        {                   //wait in here for uart interrupt
            if(check == 0)
            {
                sendMessages();  //send message to gps to recieve 0183 message
                check = 1;
            }
        }
}

void __ISR(_UART_1_VECTOR, ipl6) _U1RXInterrupt(void)
{
    putsLCD("interrupt \n \t triggered");
    if(U1STAbits.OERR == 1)
        U1STAbits.OERR = 0;

    if(U1STAbits.URXDA) //check if data is ready to be read
        {
            c = getcUART1();
            while(BusyUART1());
            if(c == '$') //c == $, hex=0x0024
            {
                count = 0;
            }

            if(count < 6)
            {
                dataTemp[count] = c;
                count++;
            }
            else if(count > 5 && count < 80)
            {
                if(dataTemp[4]=='G')
                    GGA[count]=c;
                else  //error

                count++;
            }
        }

    //parse GPS
    parseGPS();
        GPStest();              //function to test GPS
    IFS0bits.U1RXIF = 0; //clear RX interrupt flag
}
```

Comment: Maybe the UART RX pin is multiplexed and it's used by another peripheral.

Comment: Also, the code inside this statement `if(check == 0)` doesn't seems to get executed. The `check` variable is always zero (it doesn't seem to get modified anywhere).

Answer (score 3):

You enabled the UART module, but its receiver and transmitter blocks remained unpowered. You need to set:

```
U1STAbits.URXEN = 1; //enable receiver
U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1; //enable transmitter
```

Setting GPIO mode by \$\texttt{PORTSetPinsDigital}\$ is unnecessary because PIC32 automatically switches the pin setting whenever a peripheral starts to use it.

Comment: That's what drives me nuts about PICs. There's always some other bit you need to set to make things work.

Comment: looks like that was the problem, thanks for pointing it out.